# Capture dynamic button tap ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have button created programmatically in the UIImageView. This view was also created programmatically. When image in this view is tapped the button is created, now I want to capture when this button is tapped but I'm unable to here is my relevant code :

```
- (void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{ 
    MyImageView *myView = (MyImageView *)sender.view;
    NSLog(@"Image tapped is => %@", myView.currentImageName); 

    //add button to view
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(pressedPlay:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    //button image
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"playbutton.png"]];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(85.0, 175.0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height);

    myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [button setImage:backgroundImage forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
    [myView addSubview:button];
}
```

Now this code should handle the tap but for some reason it doesn't :

```
- (void)pressedPlay:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{ 
    //MyImageView *senderView = (MyImageView *) sender.view;
    NSLog(@"%@", @"I Presed button");    
}
```

Any reason why this is not working?

Comment: Does `imageTapped:` get called?

Comment: @Paul.s as with samfishers suggestions implemented, yes every time button is pressed image tapped is called

Comment: You normally use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` for a standard button interaction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suggests that you are using a `UIGestureRecognizer` (most likely a `UITapGestureRecognizer`) to detect the initial tap. The problem is that `UIGestureRecognizer` is being greedy and stopping the `UIButton` from receiving the touch.

You will need to do some shifting to disable the gesture recognizer after the initial detection and then reenable it after the play has been tapped.

[UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has the property

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled
```

or you can  choose to implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and provide an implementation of

```
gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:
```

a very simple attempt could look like:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
{
    return ![touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];
}
```

and don't forget to set the delegate on the gesture recognizer

```
myGesture.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

set the button frame from:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(85.0, 175.0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height);
```

to:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height);
```

it looks like you are setting button frame outside the imageview's frame and hence the button is not actually getting any interaction.

Comment: thanks for the response, now my button is on the image and I get image tapped event always ..

Comment: sorry i did not catch the meaning.. is it working for you now?

Answer (score 0):

The Button frame is likely setting the button outside the bounds of the UIImageView, frames are always relative to the superviews coordinate in this case the UIImageView.

Comment: similar things happens to me with HTML/CSS. What I usually do is set borders to potentially overlapping divs so I can see on my screen what's going on. Can I do something similar like set border to my UIImageView so I see on the screen where it is exactly?

Comment: @London: Yes, if you add the QuartzCore framework to your project and put #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> in your .m file, you can use view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor; and view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0; to add a 2pixel red border to any view. The overlap thing isn't actually your problem though. Paul.s's explanation above is the real reason - your gesture recogniser is stopping your button from receiving the tap. Events don't always bubble up in Cocoa like they do in JavaScript.

Comment: @nick this would also be dependant on whether the view clips to bounds.

Comment: that would affect the border drawing, but not the event handling (events don't work outside the parent frame, regardless of clipping).

Answer (score 0):

[button setExclusiveTouch:YES];